# Uniform and pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{n^a x^{n-3/2}}{1+x^n}$, $a\in \mathbb R^+, x \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Fixed $x$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f_{n,a}(x)=0$ so there is pointwise convergence in $E=(0,1)$.
Is there uniform convergence in E? 
$|f_n(x)|>{n^a \over2 } \space\forall n \ge2$ and the Sup$|f_n(x)|\ge{n^a \over2 }$ that doesn't converge to zero.
So there isn't uniform convergence in (0,1). But is there in a subset of E?

Answer (score 2):

The convergence is uniform on $(0,t)$ for any $t<1$. For this note that $|f_n(x)| \leq n^{a} t^{n-\frac 3 2}$. Now $n^{a} t^{n-\frac 3 2}=e^{(n-\frac 3 2)\log\, t +a \log\, n}\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I want to prove if it's true $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{1}f_n(x) dx=\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x) dx$.

$\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x) dx=\int_{0}^{1} 0 dx=0$.But for the first integral?